# what kind of test should I use to determine if this sequence converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

what kind of test should I use to determine if this sequence converge or diverge?
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sin\frac{1}{n}-\sin \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

Comment: Calculate the partial sums by noticing this is a telescoping series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By comparison test $$sin\frac{1}{n}-sin \frac{1}{n+1}=\\2sin(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})cos(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1})=\\2sin(\frac{1}{n(n+1)})cos(\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)})\\\leq2sin(\frac{1}{n(n+1)}) \\2\frac{1}{n(n+1)} \leq2 \frac{1}{n^2}\\$$then 
$$\sum sin\frac{1}{n}-sin \frac{1}{n+1} \leq \sum \frac{2}{n^2}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$
S = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \left(\sin\frac{1}{n}-\sin \frac{1}{n+1}\right)
= \lim_{N\to\infty}\sin\frac{1}{1} - \sin \frac{1}{N+1} =\sin 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sin\frac{1}{n}-\sin \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \left(\sin1-\sin \frac{1}{2}\right)+ \left(\sin\frac{1}{2}-\sin \frac{1}{3}\right)+\cdots+\left(\sin\frac{1}{n}-\sin \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = \sin1+\left(-\sin \frac{1}{2}+ \sin\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(-\sin \frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\sin\frac{1}{n}\right)-\sin \frac{1}{n+1}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\sin1-\sin \frac 1 n\right) = \sin 1$$